# Excel Drop Down List to show values depending on the other Cell's value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two drop down lists, one in **O12** and on in **O13** cell.
**O12** has a list of values from another Sheet named "Temp" from **S3** to **S20**, but named as "**ADList**". Next to these cells there are different values but in the same row.

I want that, whenever I choose something in the **O12**, I want it to be shown only the values next to that. Like I choose **S4** cell's value in **O12**. In **O13** there should be able to choose only that row's values.

Comment: Just a V or XLOOKUP?  You have a value in `O12` which looks up a value somewhere between `S3:S20` and returns a value from `T3:T20`?  If that's not what you want a picture would help loads.

Comment: Or do you mean you have a value that get looked up in `S3:S20` and if, for example it's finding a value in `S4` then it should transpose and display the values from `T4:Z4` in a drop-down?

Comment: Basically yes.
If choose a value from S3:S20 for example S4 then in the other drop-down there should be shown only the T4:AA4 values.

Comment: @Darren, I interpreted the OP in line with your second comment, but I agree it requires clarification. If your second comment is the correct one would also be useful to know if the possible drop-downs always have the same length or if they might differ in length

Comment: @DMM it's different almost for each row. So there are some longer and shorter lists.

Answer (score 1):

Create a named range using a formula similar to this:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$T$2:$T$20,MATCH(Sheet1!$P$2,ADList,0)):INDEX(Sheet1!$X$2:$X$20,MATCH(Sheet1!$P$2,ADList,0))
```

Your ADList is in column S, the other values are between columns `T` & `X`.  For this example I've named the return for the above formula *ReturnValues*.

Create a Data Validation list using `=ReturnValues` as the source.
I thought I'd have to transpose the values, but works without that.
It does assume all lists will be the same length - only just seen they won't be after writing this out.

[image]

**Edit:**  I tried getting the formula to shrink to the size of data, but data validation didn't like the new formula.

```
=LET(Calc, INDEX(Sheet1!$T$2:$T$20, MATCH(Sheet1!$P$2, ADList, 0)):INDEX(Sheet1!$X$2:$X$20, MATCH(Sheet1!$P$2, ADList, 0)), FILTER(Calc, Calc <> "", ))
```

Comment: Both Data Validation and the Name Manager appear a bit fussy about what they will allow. Following your approach, the following works for the second dropdown.
`=INDEX(ListAll,MATCH(B3,ADList,0),1):INDEX(ListAll,MATCH(B3,ADList,0),COUNTA(INDEX(ListAll,MATCH(B3,ADList,0),)))`
when this is assigned as `ResultsValue` in the name manager and `ListAll` is the array next to column S. Any unused elements in the rows of this array are assumed to be at the right hand end of the row.

Comment: (I used `B3` in place of the OP's `O12`)

Comment: This one looks good. It's almost working but the following error comes up and it selects the only row which fulfills the range: "You may not use reference operators (such as unions, intersections, and ranges) or array constants for Data Validation criteria."

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find out the correct formula:

> =IF(O12<>"", INDEX(ListAll, MATCH(O12, ADList, 0), 0), "")

**ListAll** contains all the possible return values.
**ADList** contains all the choosable values for O12 Cell